# Olympics Schedule IMPORTXML - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

UPDATE - examples clarified

How do I persuade `IMPORTXML` to grab **either** the empty `<td>` elements or a specific attribute three nodes down, if it exists?

--

I'm trying to pull the schedule from the [Olympics website](https://olympics.com/tokyo-2020/en/schedule/) into a G Sheet for #reasons. I got as far as `IMPORTHTML` will not do the thing that I want, and then spent more hours than I care to mention banging my head against `IMPORTXML` and XPath. This is the closest I've gotten:

```
=importxml("https://olympics.com/tokyo-2020/en/schedule/","//[@id='schBoxInner']/table/tbody/tr")
```

This successfully pulls the right row headers, and apparently also all the appropriate `<td>` column elements into G Sheets, because if I type in the (empty) columns, I get a `#REF` error.

It seems to me like this should be easy - I want a table of the days events are taking place, and whether or not an event is occurring. for example, the opening ceremonies are on the 23rd (which, because of their wonky table, is column D:

|  | 21st | 22nd | 23rd | 24th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Opening ceremonies |  |  | TRUE |  |
| Basketball |  |  |  | TRUE |

The trick is that it's not a `TRUE` value on that date: It's `<a href=blah><img=blah></a>`. I just want to include SOMETHING in that cell in G Sheets, because with my previous formulation it displays...nothing.

If it's actually supposed to be this hard, please tell me now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave specific examples of what you are trying to select with XPath.  I can't make sense of what you consider the "child", "grandchild", etc. elements.  The only specifics you gave is "ALT text on the image" but it is not clear how that relates to your stated purpose.

Comment: Updated for clarity, I hope, @DavidDenenberg . I really just want it to display some value (any value) when the `<td>` element has a child node.

Comment: As I'm reading your comment more fully, I'm reflecting that perhaps, yes, the Purpose is not clear...Ultimately, I'm attempting to build a G Sheet that is similar to the table they have on the Olympics Website, there...with the days that specific events are being run, and/or whether there are medal ceremonies. Or...that's where I started...

Now I'm just trying to figure out why a thing that I think should be simple is NOT SIMPLE in XPath, because it's new to me and I think it's an interesting problem. =P

Comment: Question remains unanswered, despite @Deera's excellent feedback. Is this possible? 

In thinking about it more, part of what became apparent is that there IS content in the TD for every relevant cell...but there's no TEXT, and that seems to be what is desired by XPath/Google Sheets. 

I'm going to let this one continue simmering, and maybe come back to it later.

Comment: Honestly, too much time to match up your narrative in the question with the details of what you are trying to select.  XPath selects a list of nodes.   Show a concrete example of which nodes you want to select with your single expression and a detailed answer will likely be more readily provided by the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Wikipedia for the Olympics Calendar @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:2020_Summer_Olympics_calendar

You can Just use,

```
=importhtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:2020_Summer_Olympics_calendar","table",3)
```

to get the table. [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4QtYBtAdTAG6qbEBhleMW5izPqH0XsmiQZM07WMs64/edit?usp=sharing)